# EAR archive inside another EAR using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Can you put an ear archive inside another ear archive? I have tried adding an ear dependency to an ear module specifying artifact type as
`<type>ear</type>`
with maven 3.3.3 but I get
`Failed to initialize ear modules: Unknown artifact type[ear]`
If I don't specify an artifact type then maven looks for a jar artifact and fails to find it.
Is there a way to do it? If not, is there a reason to prohibit inner ear archives?

Comment: As ear files are just zip files, the basic but useless answer is yes.  What is the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to merge two rather complex (but well tested) projects into one and I would very much like not to copy paste or duplicate effort by rewriting code.

Comment: Only jar, ejb and war are supported cause ear does not make sense.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense in terms of project development - Project 1 may use Project 2 as a component with Project 2 maintaining its structure. Inner ears would definitely make pom.xml more readable too.

Comment: I do not think the Java EE specification allows for deploying EARs inside EARs.

Comment: I have been going through the J7EE spec (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-spec/JavaEE_Platform_Spec.pdf?AuthParam=1437040821_5eb75b95a2bef86e817130bc259734ae) but have not found that kind of restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `EAR` archive can only contain `WAR`, `JAR` and `RAR` (Resource Archive) modules.

If you have an EAR project in Maven, you should add your EJB dependencies like this one:

```
<dependency>
    <type>ejb</type>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

and configure the `maven-ear-plugin` similarly

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <modules>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For `WAR` dependencies you need to use `<type>war</type>` and `<webModule>` instead.

Comment: Actually maven EAR plugin allows you to work with many more types and even add custom type artifacts: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html#Custom_Artifact_Types So I guess the question is really: do application servers support inner ears? Or why don't they?

Comment: I could not find an exact document on it, but the EAR file format is specified in some JSR, and it quite thoroughly describes it. And it does not allow EAR inside an EAR (though it does not disallow it either). Which sounds reasonable for me, because applications should be a self-contained, not strictly dependent on each other. By the way, why not configure another EAR Maven module which contains the components of the other EAR?

Comment: Not disallowing sounds like allowing to me). I can move ear components, no doubt about it, but I want to know where did the inner ear restriction come from.

Comment: AFAIIK something which is not specified in any JSR, should result in undefined behaviour, so even if you could use nested EARs, you should not depend on it. What's is the use case by the way, I am not sure I get it.

Comment: Inner ears would allow more precise business projects to software projects mapping and make pom.xml more readable.